# surface integrals — is it "dx" or "ds"?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

I was reading this [note](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/ma131/surfaceintegrals.pdf) about Surface Integrals and came across this paragraph:

> Let S be a surface parameterized by $\mathbf X : D → \mathbf R^3$. 
>   A point $(s_0, t_0) \in D$, is mapped to $\mathbf X(s_0, t_0) \in\mathbb  R^3$. 
>   An infinitesimal $dx × dt$ parallelogram at $(s_0, t_0) \in D$ has area $dx dt$. It’s mapped to an infinitesimal $\mathbf T_s(s_0, t_0)ds × \mathbf T_t(s_0, t_0)$ rectangle with area $||\mathbf T_s × \mathbf T_t|| ds dt$, which equals $\|\mathbf N\| ds dt$. 
>   We’ll call this infinitesimal parallelogram the surface area differential, denoted $dS$.

I'm quite new to the topic, and I kind of got confused here. When the note says "An infinitesimal $dx \times dt$ parallelogram... has area $dx dt$", are the $dx$'s supposed to be $ds$'s? Otherwise, if $dx$ is right, could someone help me understand why we use $dx$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe $dx$ should be $ds$. I believe also $T_s(s_0, t_0)ds \times T_t(s_0, t_0)$ should be $T_s(s_0, t_0)ds \times T_t(s_0, t_0)dt$.